# How can I return result of string Kusto Query from c#

Tags: c#, azure, c#-4.0, azure-data-explorer

```
var kusto = string.Format("let MyData = CompanyMydata" +
                " | where ID == 'Z123' | top 1 by dateTimeUtc desc");

            var reader = client.ExecuteQuery(kusto);
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                //how can i return coming result as list of string or json string?
            }
```

In `while loop` I can able to return single column value one by one by using
`string state = reader.GetString(1);` but i want to return complete result instead of one by one column value.
so that i can do `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(resultString);` to specific class.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

assuming you're using the client libraries mentioned [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/kusto/api/netfx/about-the-sdk), you should be able to do something like the following:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var kcsb = new KustoConnectionStringBuilder("https://help.kusto.windows.net").WithAadUserPromptAuthentication();
        var databaseName = "Samples";

        using (var queryProvider = KustoClientFactory.CreateCslQueryProvider(kcsb))
        {
            var clientRequestProperties = new ClientRequestProperties() { ClientRequestId = "Sample;" + Guid.NewGuid() };
            var query = "StormEvents | summarize count(), max(EndTime) by State";
            var result = queryProvider.ExecuteQuery<MyType>( // focus on this part
                databaseName,
                query,
                clientRequestProperties)
                .ToList();

            foreach (var row in result)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"State = {row.State}, Count = {row.Count}, MaxEndTime = {row.MaxEndTime}");
            }
        }
    }

    class MyType
    {
        public string State;
        public long Count;
        public DateTime MaxEndTime;
    }
```

Comment: I have one question here: for me <MyType>.ToList() not getting filled with data. though the query returning results. Any guess why?

Comment: have you made sure you have public properties in your class?

Comment: Yes, I did that. See the complete code here: https://github.com/Chandan-Baba/azure-kusto-c-app/blob/master/Program.cs

Comment: remove the `{get; set;}`s. please see the example above and follow it as-is (any questions you ask which don't disclose changes you've made make it harder to answer your questions, with the assumption you're running the same code and getting different results)

Comment: @Yoni Thanks for the suggestion. It worked for me only after removing the getters and setters. But why so?

Comment: @VinayMundada looks like Kusto ObjectReader can not deserialize data using public properties only fields.